# Cloning a field with text in it clones text as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that clones three fields, but when it clones the three fields, it also clones the text entered inside of it, is there a way to clear the content inside of the field when it is cloned?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedSection').length;
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

        var newSection = $('#clonedSection' + num).clone().attr('id', 'clonedSection' + newNum);

        newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'age' + newNum).attr('name', 'age' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(3)').children(':first').attr('id', 'school' + newNum).attr('name', 'school' + newNum);

        $('.clonedSection').last().append(newSection);
        $('.clonedSection').last().val(ping);

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

        if (newNum == 2)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#clonedSection' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you're doing [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) you can find/clear the fields, like this:

```
.clone().find(':text, textarea').val('').end()
```

If you don't have `<textarea>` elements you an leave out that bit, what this does is perform a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the text elements, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to clear them and [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to return the chain afterwards to using the coned element, not the text elements we were looking for.

Or, alternative, if these lines are your inputs:

```
newSection.children(....)
```

just add a `.val('')` on the end of each , for example the first could look like this:

```
newSection.find('> :first > :first').attr({'id': 'name' + newNum, 'name': 'name' + newNum }).val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `value` attribute to an empty string using `.attr("value", "")` (I'm assuming you're talking about a `<input type="text" />`):

```
newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum).attr('value', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the input elements like this:

```
newSection.find(':input').val('');
```