# Cloning a field without cloning the text as well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that clones three fields, but when it clones the three fields, it also clones the text entered inside of it, is there a way to clear the content inside of the field when it is cloned?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedSection').length;
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

        var newSection = $('#clonedSection' + num).clone().attr('id', 'clonedSection' + newNum);

        newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'age' + newNum).attr('name', 'age' + newNum);
        newSection.children(':nth-child(3)').children(':first').attr('id', 'school' + newNum).attr('name', 'school' + newNum);

        $('.clonedSection').last().append(newSection);
        $('.clonedSection').last().val(ping);

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

        if (newNum == 2)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $('#clonedSection' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Why are you asking the exact same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467457/cloning-a-field-with-text-in-it-clones-text-as-well

Comment: No reason, was an accident! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the input elements like this:

```
newSection.find(':input').val('');
```